# How to put a 100% TICK or VRULE for unknown data with RRDTool

Tags: rrdtool

I'm plotting a number of data on various graphs using RRDTool, occasionally I get unknown data points, this is totally expected especially if the computer updating the RRDs is offline.

That's cool, however, when this happens, I want there to be a nice big red line (for each and every unkonwn so it makes the graph's viewer very aware that the value at those points is not `0`, but actually `UNKNOWN`.

What I have:
[image: RRDTool Graph showing Load Average]

What I want (Photoshopped):
[image]

Is there an easy/elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked:

I used the `CDEF` with an existing Data Source (DS) instead of having to create a new DS.

I added the following 2 lines in my RRDTool Graph section

```
'CDEF:up=a1,0,*,0,EQ,0,1,IF' \
'TICK:up#DB0865:1.0'         \
```

The `CDEF` doe the calculation of:

a1 * 0

Then compares the the result of that to 0. If they're equal, set "up" to "0" else set "up" to "1".

The only time that they would not be equal, would be if "a1" was unknown.

Therefore when there is a gap in the graph (no data), it will have a 100% vertical bar (TICK) of a deep purple/pink colour (`#DB0865`)

Even though the documentation on the [RRDTool site](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdtune.en.html) Indicates that a DS can be added to an existing RRD, it actually cannot be (according to Tobi Oetiker). So I went with the above method to avoid losing all the data in the rrds that I already have when creating a new rrd with a new DS.

Here's an example of how it looks:
[image: RRD Graph showing unknown data highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

The elegant way would be to check if load includes any reasonable value. If not add 1 to DS that you create for this purpose.

So for Robin Database add new DS that will have value 0 or 1

```
DS:somestatus1:GAUGE:600:U:U
```

and then start adding 0 or 1 to this DS if your primary DS is not available

at the end for drawing the graph:

```
DEF:somestatus1=$RRD_FILE:somestatus1:AVERAGE \
CDEF:my_status_cdef=somestatus1,1,0,IF \
TICK:my_status_cdef#e0ffe0:1.0:"Device was ON\n" \
```

each TICK will draw 100% height vertical bar over the graph as you need

Another option is to create conditional CDEF that will create TICK if primary DS is none.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to be using this for a lot of different graphs, not just Load Average. Could I not use the unknown value with a `CDEF`? or is RPN purely numeric? - I'm thinking: something like: `CDEF:new=loadAverage,U,1,0,IF`

Comment: if CDEF IS purely numeric, then maybe I can do something like this with an existing DS... `CDEF:new=loadAverage,0,*,0,NE,1,0,IF` Which I interpret as: If `loadaverage x 0` is not equal to "0" then send result value "1". Would the `result x 0` become `nan` rather than `0` if the value is unknown?

Comment: Looks like `NE` not in the CDEF for RRDTOOL, so I used `EQ` instead and swapped the then/else conditions and it works! (yay)

Comment: Upvote for leading me down the CDEF/TICK path, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This method plots an area when "offline". The `CDEF` checks if the `load` measurement is `UN` (unknown), if it is, it will return `1`, multiply by `INF` to make it to the highest value of the plot.

```
CDEF:offline=load,UN,INF,* \
AREA:offline#FF000011: \
```